# Could Obama have passed Obamacare in the first 2 years when the Dems controlled both houses?

Tags: united-states, congress

Is it true that Democrats controlled both houses for c. 2 years? If so, couldn’t the president have passed the big ones, like health care reform, immigration reform, etc., at that time? And if he had the support then, why didn’t he do it?

Comment: ummm.... he did and he did pass health care.  He doesnt actually want immigration reform.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about motivations and reasoning of a specific person not political processes.

Comment: "Is it true that Democrats controlled both houses for @ 2 years?" - is there anything basic Wikipedia articles on US House and Senate in 2008 don't cover on this specific question?

Comment: The answer is yes and he did pass the ACA at that time.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, President Barack Obama could have passed Obamacare in the first two years of his presidency, given that the Democrats controlled both houses.

We know this [because he did.](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/03/24/health/policy/24health.html)